# MediatR PipelineBehavior error message Unable to resolve service for type 'FluentValidation.IValidator`1

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, mediatr

I have this `ValidationBehavior`

```
public sealed class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IValidator<TRequest> _validator;

    public ValidationBehavior(IValidator<TRequest> validator)
    {
        _validator = validator;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        _validator.ValidateAndThrow(request);
        return await next();
    }
}
```

I have this handler

```
public class RemoveCurrencyHandler : IRequestHandler<RemoveCurrencyCommand, Unit>
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;

    public RemoveCurrencyHandler(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(RemoveCurrencyCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var currency = await _context.Currency.FindAsync(request.Id);

        if (currency is null)
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();

        _context.Remove(currency);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error message `Unable to resolve service for type 'FluentValidation.IValidator'` everytime I call this handler, now obviously I know the reason is because I'm missing the validator, so it goes away if I add this

```
public class RemoveCurrencyValidator : AbstractValidator<RemoveCurrencyCommand>
{

}
```

but not all my handler need a `Validator`, so I don't want to add empty `Validator` class to handler that doesn't need it. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

The MediatR validator pieplines enable you to execute validation logic before and after your Command or Query Handlers execute.
You can update the constructor of `ValidationBehavior` class to expect an `IEnumerable<IValidator>`. So that we can always resolve the class (the list will be empty if you don't implement the `Validator`)

```
// ValidationBehavior
public sealed class ValidationBehavior<TRequest, TResponse> : IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IEnumrable<IValidator<TRequest>> _validators;

    public ValidationBehavior(IEnumerable<IValidator<TRequest>> validators)
    {
        _validators = validators;
    }

    public async Task<TResponse> Handle(TRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate<TResponse> next)
    {
        if(_validators.Any())
        {
            var validationResults = await Task.WhenAll(_validators.Select(v => v.ValidateAndThrow(request)));

            var failures = validationResults.SelectMany(r => r.Errors).Where(f => f != null).ToList();
            if (failures.Count != 0)
                throw new ValidationException(failures);
        }
        return await next();
    }
}
```